# swift 4 Alamofire parsing data and show it on UILabel?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, alamofire

Here is my code below.
I want to utilize Alamofire to get the data in the url below and parse it in to several UILabels...
How can I get the data and parse it to the UILabel?
Please help me.... (the data in the URL is in JSON)

```
"//(code 200)
{
    ""message"": ""Successful Get Board Data"",
    ""data"": [
    {
        ""board_idx"": 2,
        ""board_title"": ""testing"",
        ""board_content"": ""testing"",
        ""board_views"": 0,
        ""board_photo"": null,
        ""board_writetime"": ""2018-04-27 15:04:03"",
        ""user_id"": ""ㅇㅇ""
        }

    ]
}"          
    func showDetail(title: String, content: String, comment: String) {
    let URL = "http://______________/board"
    let body: [String: Any] = [
        "user_id" : gsno(userdefault.string(forKey: "nickName")),
        "board_title" : title,
        "board_content" : content,
        "comment_content" : comment
    ]
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData() { res in
        switch res.result {
        case .success:


            break
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            break

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: edit your question with response

Comment: @Sh_Khan What do you mean?

Comment: How will we help you without knowing the response json

Comment: @Sh_Khan I added Json but, don't know if that's what you want to have

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise Swift Decodeables to get the data from the response and turn it into an object from which you can populate the label.

```
struct BoardData: Decodable {
    var message: String
    var data: [BoardInfo]
}

struct BoardInfo: Decodable {
   var board_idx: Int?
   var board_title: String?
   var board_content: String?
   var board_views: Int?
   var board_writetime: String?
   var user_id: String?
}
```

With this you can then parse the response directly from Alamofire, within your

```
case .success:
```

i.e

```
let json = res.data
    do{
        let boardResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(BoardData.self,from: json!)     
        boardTitleLabel.text = boardResponse.data[0].board_title
     }catch {
       print("Error: \(error)")
     }
```

If any of the types are incorrect i.e user_id looks to be a string in your JSON but I'd presume its an Int, change them in the Decodable provided above and you'll be good to go.

If you wish to give the variables more standard names i.e boardTitle as opposed to board_title, take a look at CodingKeys, as this will allow you to specify serialised names.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: user_id & board_title should be strings

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pair Alamofire with SwiftyJSON, which, in my opinion, really helps when it comes to handling JSON data. It converts the Alamofire data into a workable format, and allows you to parse the data really easily as well.

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Usage example:

```
    Alamofire.request("http://samplesite.com/api/data.php", method: .post, parameters: someJSONIfNeeded, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(let responseJSON):
                let recievedJson = JSON (responseJSON) //Use SwiftyJSON to convert the received data
//Parse the data using the SwiftyJSON functions, and add the needed data to labels.
                completion (true, nil) //Return true if the function succeeds.
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion (false, error)//Return false if the function fails.
            }

        }
```